# FindTest / Check if folder already exists not working as intended

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm currently using a Google Apps Script to create a new folder in a draft directory based on the values of spreadsheet column A + B.

A find test has already been implemented to check if the folder already exists. However, the problem is the find doesn't seem to pass the test, so the on-edit script duplicate sub-folders that are already created.

I'm looking for some help to troubleshoot why the duplicates are being created when the check has already been implemented in the code.

For example, after a sub-folder is created in drafts, it will create more with the exact same name, when it should not do this because a folder already exists.

The script should

1. Check if folder already exists
2. Get FolderIterator for looking into status folders
3. Checks if Parent Folder already has Folder with given name

```js
function createFolderSubFolders(e) {
   // Get Parent folder
   var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1sx-kSgfnZiZKQQ8wrBZ8OOKVSm8dpsa-');
   var draftFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1GeLEyqnrAKh-cvVdTjG6s8YEM3VuB-FO');
   var liveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1mhkW4tU5Uo7gyzWgpzzIzaEh-G57flj6');
   var archveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1t1XnfNn5vDbXxSagNDCsLSKjrMl2pnhs');
   // Get current spreadsheet
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1hpzF587f6k5TZyRrNVxuf5bClB26Pqsk8YitbGMtBmg');
   var i = e.range.getRow();
   //process if column B is not empty
   if (ss.getRange('B' + i).getValue() != '') {
      //Set intended folder name
      var ref = ss.getRange('A' + i).getDisplayValue();
      var location = ss.getRange('B' + i).getValue();
      var status = ss.getRange('C' + i).getValue();
      var propertyFolderName = ref + ' - ' + location;

      //Check if folder already exists
      var findTest = false;
      //Get FolderIterator for looking into status folders
      var statusFolders = parentFolder.getFolders();
      //Checks if Parent Folder already has Folder with given name
      while (statusFolders.hasNext() && findTest == false && status != '') {
         var statusFolder = statusFolders.next();

         //Property Listings in current iterated status folder.
         var propertyFolders = statusFolder.getFolders();
         while (propertyFolders.hasNext() && findTest == false) {
            var propertyFolder = propertyFolders.next();
            if (propertyFolderName == propertyFolder.getName()) {
               //Check where property folder lies currently.
               var statusFoldername = statusFolder.getName();
               findTest = true;
               break;
            }
         }
      }
      // Create new folder in draftFolder if not already created.
      if (findTest == false) {
         var propertyFolder = draftFolder.createFolder(propertyFolderName);
         var newSubFolder = propertyFolder.createFolder(newSubFolderName);
      }
      //Otherwise check if folder needs to be moved to other section.
   } else if ((status == 'Live' && statusFoldername != 'BPA Live Listings') || (status == 'Archived' && statusFoldername != 'BPA Archived Listings')) {
      //Set folder where to move the propertyFolder
      if (statusFoldername != 'BPA Live Listings') {
         var moveToFolder = liveFolder;
      } else {
         var moveToFolder = archveFolder;
      }
      propertyFolder.moveTo(moveToFolder);
   }
}
}
```

Comment: If you're asking a debugging question, provide debugging details -logs. See secrets of debugging in [mcve]. You may even find your answer, when trying the first step of "restarting from scratch"

Answer (score 0):

I developpe a function who will give you the answer if a STRING is a folder existe or not.

```
function SearchFolder(pValeur) {

    /////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////
    //Cette fonction nous permet
    //de tester si un répertoire
    //existe et d'extraire toutes
    //les informations nécessaires
    //Ici on rentre ID ou le nom
    //du répertoire
    /////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////
    var share = 'non';
    var namefolder = '';
    var idfolder = '';
    /////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////
    var etat = typeof(pValeur)==='string';
    /////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////
    if(etat==true)
    {
        /////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////
        //Extraction Folder Partagés
        var shareDrive = Drive.Drives.list();
                var sharekey = Object.keys(shareDrive);
        /////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////
        var listeFolderShare = new Array();
        if(ToolsArray_Exist('items',shareDrive))
        {
            var xtiems = shareDrive['items'];
            if(xtiems.length>0)
            {
                listeFolderShare = xtiems;
            }
        }
        /////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////
        //Testons si le folder est privé avec son nom
        var infoRep = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(pValeur);
        var cdtA = infoRep.hasNext();
        /////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////
        //Testons si le folder est avec un id
        //ici ca fonctionne meme si le folder
        //est partagés
        var cdtB = false;
        if(cdtA==false)
        {
            try {
                infoRep = DriveApp.getFolderById(pValeur);
                namefolder = infoRep.getName();
                idfolder = pValeur;
                cdtB = true;
            }
            catch(err) {}
        }
        /////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////
        //Testons si le folder est partagé
        var cdtC = false;
        if(cdtB==false | namefolder=='Drive')
        {
            if(listeFolderShare.length>0)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < listeFolderShare.length; i++)
                {
                    var vectItem = listeFolderShare[i];
                    var itemName = vectItem['name'];
                    var itemId = vectItem['id'];

                    if(itemName==pValeur)
                    {
                        share = 'oui';
                        namefolder = itemName;
                        idfolder = itemId;
                        cdtC = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(itemId==pValeur)
                        {
                            share = 'oui';
                            namefolder = itemName;
                            idfolder = itemId;
                            cdtB = true;
                            break;
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////
        if(cdtA==true)
        {
            var folder = infoRep.next();
            idfolder = folder.getId();
            namefolder = pValeur;
        }
        /////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////
    }
    /////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////
    var resultat = new Object();
    resultat['etat'] = etat;
    resultat['share'] = share;
    resultat['id'] = idfolder;
    resultat['name'] = namefolder;
    /////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////
    return resultat;
    /////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////
}
```

Comment: Exemple 1 : my string is supposly an ID
Value = "4qs5d41cqs5d1q5s20"
res = SearchFolder(Value);
var etat = res['etat'];
var id_folder = res['id'];
var name_folder = res['name'];

if the string is really an ID
then etat = true and id_folder = value and the name = xxxxxxx
if not then
then etat = false and id_folder = '' and the name = ''

Comment: Exemple 2 : my string is supposly an NAME_FOLDER
Value = "myDesktopPro" (it is an exemple name)
res = SearchFolder(Value);
var etat = res['etat'];
var id_folder = res['id'];
var name_folder = res['name'];

if the string is really an NAME_FOLDER
then etat = true and id_folder = '54q5sd45q4sdqsdq545' and the name = myDesktopPro
if not then
then etat = false and id_folder = '' and the name = ''